# Numbers with degrees in tabular enviroment

Tags: tables, math-mode, superscripts

Good time of the day.
When I compile code with `2^{25}`, the Latex processor gives me following error:

> Missing $ inserted. \end{align*} .

But when I write simply `$2$` in second row, then there are no errors reported.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{extarticle}


\usepackage[a4paper, top=1 cm, bottom=1.5 cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{  amsthm, amssymb,latexsym,amsfonts}
\usepackage[leqno,fleqn]{amsmath}


\setlength{\mathindent}{0 pt}

\begin{document}


\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
{\small
\begin{align*}
\begin{tabular}{*{26}{|c}|}
\hline
\text{x=} &1&0&0&0&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&1&1&1\\
\hline 
\textrm{bit }& 1&2^{25}&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{align*}
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, your code is not the best one to produce what you want. But... I think that `tabular` contents is text mode so you need `$2^{25}$`.

Answer (score 5):

The contents of a `tabular` environment are processed in text mode by default, even if the `tabular` environment occurs inside a display-math environment such as `align*`. Since the `^` character has a special meaning in TeX and LaTeX documents, you need to switch to math mode in order to get `2^{25}` processed correctly, assuming you want to keep using a `tabular` environment.

I would suggest, though, that you employ an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. I further suggest that you replace `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}` with `\[` and `\]` since you're not making use of the added capabilities of the `align*` environment.

Aside: (a) The `amssymb` package loads the `amsfonts` package automatically -- no need to load it explicitly. (b) Since you're loading the `amssymb` package, there can be no rational justification for loading the `latexsym` package as well. Incidentally, the `latexsym` package is obsolete, *unless* you still need to compile a LaTeX document in LaTeX2.09 compatibility mode; however, that's not the case here. (c) The correct way to write the document class option is `11pt`, not `11 pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1cm, bottom=1.5cm, hmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[leqno,fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
{%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\small
\[
\begin{array}{*{26}{|c}|}
\hline
x= &1&0&0&0&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&1&1&1\\
\hline 
\textrm{bit }& 1&2^{25}&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25\\
\hline 
\end{array}
\]
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to know: any reason for a space in `\textrm{bit }`?

Comment: @Sigur - The OP wrote `\textrm{bit }`. I was assuming -- possibly incorrectly -- that the OP had a good reason for not writing `\textrm{bit}`, i.e., for *not* omitting the space after `bit`...